# div is overflowing even when max-height and break word wrapping

Tags: css, flexbox

html (pug)

```
div.result
    div.imageSidebar
        div.actionButtons
            button.hideSimilarButton ⛔
            button.showAtActualScaleButton(onclick=`showAtActualScale(${index})`) ⭕
        div.infoDiv
            - let similarImageLink = encodeURIComponent(imageName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "").replace(/\d+$/, "").replace(/\(\d*\)|\d+$/g, "").trim())
            a.imageTitle(href='/search?searchText='+similarImageLink)
                | #{imageName} 
            - let folderlink = encodeURIComponent(folderName)
            a.subTitle(href='/search?searchText='+folderlink)
                |#{folderName}
    div.mainContent.scrollbarVisible
        - let imageLinkEscaped = encodeURIComponent(imagePath)
        a#contentLink(href='/?imageBackLink=' + imageLinkEscaped)
            if (imagePath.endsWith('.mp4') || imagePath.endsWith('.webm') || imagePath.endsWith('.mkv'))
                video.searchVid.resultFile(id='image'+index,src=imageLinkEscaped controls loop)
            else
                img.searchImg.resultFile(id='image'+index,src=imageLinkEscaped)
```

css

```
    .results {
        display: flex;
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin: 0;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .result {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .imageSidebar {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 0;
        align-items: flex-start;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .actionButtons {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    .actionButtons>* {
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 22px;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: black;
        border: solid;
        border-color: gray;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0px 2.5px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .infoDiv {
        display: flex;
        flex-grow: 1;
        align-content: flex-start;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: break-word;
    }

    .imageTitle,
    .subTitle {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        writing-mode: vertical-rl;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        /* max-height: 100%; */
        align-self: flex-start;
        /* text-align: right; */
        width: fit-content;
    }

    .imageTitle {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    .subTitle {
        color: gray;
        font-size: 25px;
    }   
    
    .mainContent {
        display: flex;
        align-content: flex-start;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .resultFile {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        /* remove below line to disable upscaling of small images */
        min-height: auto;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
```

Only when there is wrapping involved the css properties are not respected and text goes beyond what should be 100% of the available space

At the top position: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNWBi.jpg)
It seems to be taking the extra height of the buttons in 100% too: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euYOv.jpg)
Other one without wrapping seems to calculate height correctly: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJxqM.jpg)
Even the flex-start is not being respected: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Geakw.jpg)

I have tried all the css properties and want to know what is that I'm missing.
100% is getting evaluated correctly otherwise so why is wrapping breaking it?

Comment: You will get a lot more eyes to help you if you show the generated HTML and not a pug file.

Comment: I agree with @Rob, we're also missing context. Your `.results`div has a `height`of `100%`, but what about it's parent? Height of 100% needs the parent to have a fixed height.